# Task.Run in callback C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, task

Assuming I have a callback method that looks like this:

```
private void Callback_eventcalled(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Process(e.value);
    });
}
```

When the task starts, does it create a new copy of the value? Or is the callback method blocked untill it is finished processing (this would break the need for the task in the first place). I have not found a good test method.

Comment: if `e.value` is value type - new copy, if reference - it will reference to same object without blocking.

Comment: to wait in callback for finish of `var tsk = Task.Run() ` you need to put it's returned balue to variable (lets say it's named "tsk") and call `tsk.Wait()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it create a new copy of the value

It depends on what is the type of `e.value`

[Passing Value-Type Parameters and Passing reference-Type Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t0za5es.aspx)

```
    private  void Button_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 5;
        Task.Run(() => Process(i)).Wait();

        MessageBox.Show("From button_click: "+i.ToString());
    }

    public void Process(int w)
    {
            MessageBox.Show("From task-1: "+ w.ToString());
            w++;
            MessageBox.Show("From task-2: "+ w.ToString());
    }
```

Here `i` is an integer,a value-type and passed by value, so a copy will be made and hence the increment made in the `Process()` won't be reflected back in the caller.

Below, `i` is passed as a reference so the increment in `Process()` will be reflected back in the caller.

```
    private  void Button_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 5;
        Task.Run(() => Process(ref i)).Wait();

        MessageBox.Show("From button_click: "+i.ToString());
    }

    public void Process(ref int w)
    {

            MessageBox.Show("From task-1: "+ w.ToString());
            w++;
            MessageBox.Show("From task-2: " + w.ToString());

    }
```

If the `Wait()` is removed, there will be no blocking, but the Task may run after the code lines in the caller, and hence the value of `i` from caller can still be 5